# how to import sql server data into google doc

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, google-docs-api

We have to sync website inquiries which is stored in sql server 2008 into google doc dynamically.
Website is developed in c#, asp.net. Please suggest on this.

Answer (score 0):

Google docs has an API for that.

The Google Documents List Data API allows client applications to programmatically access and manipulate user data stored with Google Documents.

Check it's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/?hl=en&csw=1), it has examples and everything you would need to develop something based on google docs.